# Signal-to-noise ratio calculation for audio signal

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I was applying a noise cancellation algorithm on a noisy audio file. I got good result. After that I calculated the SNR of the signal with noise and without noise. According to the theory, the SNR should increase for noise-free audio. But my results show a decrement.

Note: I used the implementation of scipy.stats.signaltonoise( ). As this is only useful to non-negative variables, i modified scipy.stats.signaltonoise( ) function. I divided numpy array of audio signal by the maximum element of that array. Then I took the square of each element of that array. By doing this, I made all the elements non-negative.

Here is the modified function-

```
def signaltonoise(a, axis=0, ddof=0):

    mx = np.amax(a)
    a = np.divide(a,mx)
    a = np.square(a)
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    m = a.mean(axis)
    sd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof)
    return np.where(sd == 0, 0, m/sd)
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post a small sample of the data contained in your variable ‘a’?

Comment: Here is the first 10 elements of data for each signal.

A = [1628455 -2086173 -12900746 -20843518 -19398716 -10064665 -513033 -922726 -14679730]

B = [-1873027 -2033412 -2122975 -2220279 -2305735 -2341386 -2202931 -1912976 -1579040 ]

A is the data of noisy signal and B is the data of noise-free signal

Comment: I copied your code and sample data. The results I get are in line with your expectations: noisy data set A returns an SNR value of 0.9121966 and noise-free data set B returns an SNR value of 4.73277. Maybe there is something in your full data set that is skewing your results?

Comment: Not an answer but a question, what does 'a' mean, is it the array of amplitudes or frequencies? Sorry, I am new to this domain, curious about the same!